# Logith transformation

Tags: matlab

I calculated a cubic polynomials which is an output of Response Surface Methodology. My actual output is between 0 and 1, but my regression has, of course, negative values. So I want to transform this to 0 and 1 interval. I tried logit transformation with

```
   t = exp(max*y-min);
   x = 1 ./ (1+t);
```

but, it does not god job. What are other transformation options? For the blue line, I cannot have negative values.

[image: two muppets]

Comment: Only YOU know what defines a good job. max(0,z) might be perfect, but we cannot know. My point is, you need to explain what was wrong with what you tried before anyone can give an intelligent answer.

Comment: I edit the plot, basically when I use logit transformation for the dashed line to approximate green line, Logit gives me red line. I a looking for a transformation technique that will do a better job than logit

Comment: Don't you also have to transform the original data for comparison?

Comment: My point is that I want to find a transformation technique such that blue line will converge to green. When I applied Logit Transformation, blue line becomes red line. So I am looking for different transformation techniques.

Comment: The blue line does not look like a cubic polynomial. What is your polynomial equation resulting from RSM regression?